# Change pixels within sliding window -Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hi I have implemented a sliding window over an image in matlab using this code:

```
N = 32;
info = repmat(struct, ceil(size(Z, 1) / N), ceil(size(Z, 2) / N)); 
for row = 1:N:size(Z, 1)%loop through each pixel in the image matrix
 for col = 1:N:size(Z, 2)
     r = (row - 1) / N + 1;
     c = (col - 1) / N + 1;

      imgWindow = Z(row:min(end,row+N-1), col:min(end,col+N-1));


      average = mean(imgWindow(:)); 
      window(r, c).average=average;


     % if mean pixel intensity is greater than 200 then keep the window for
     % further inspection. If not then discard the window.

     if average<200
       imgWindow=false;
     end 

  end 
end 


figure(2);
imshow(Z);
```

The aim of this code is to check the mean intensity within each sliding window and if the mean intensity is less than 200 then turn the pixels inside the window black.

However when I try to view the resulting image after the sliding window and travelled the whole image , I just see the orginal image again.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is missing functionality that will actually set the sliding window portion of the image to black if the window intensity is less than 200.  There is the following block:

```
if average<200
   imgWindow=false;
 end
```

but there is no corresponding line of code to set the original block in the image **Z** to zero.

I think what you want to do is create a copy of the original image:

```
ZWindowed = Z;
```

then continue as before, grabbing the window from **Z**.  When the window intensity is less than 200, then do the following:

```
if average<200
   % zero out the data corresponding to the window
   ZWindowed(row:min(end,row+N-1), col:min(end,col+N-1)) = 0;
 end
```

Then display the image less those windows whose intensity is less than 200:

```
imshow(ZWindowed);
```

The above code assumes that the image is mxn only (and so is not RGB).

Comment: Hi again, this shows Zwindowed as a grayscale image with most of it 'blacked out' but not all of it. However when I do display(ZWindowed)' it shows a matrix consisting of all 0's. Do you know why this would be ?

Comment: What is the size of your matrix?  Are you sure that the console window is fitting in all the values from ZWindowed?  Try **find(ZWindowed>0)** and that will return the indices of all non-zero values in the matrix.